# Linking directly to both parent+child views/controllers from the main navigation menu

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Consider this example:

The main router is located in

app.js

- someparent/childroute1
- someparent/childroute2
- route3

"someparent" is the "base controller and view". It has some reusable html markup in the view, custom elements and bindings which is to be shared by all its "child views and controllers". The child views and controllers will access these.

Inside "someparent.html" there's (besides the shared markup) also a `<router-view>` tag, in which the child routes and pages should be rendered inside, but there's no navigation inside someparent.html.

From the main router/routes in app.js it should be possible to click a link and land - not on the parent/base class "someparent" itself, but directly on the children of the "someparent" "base/parent views and controllers", rendering both, when you click a link in the navigation menu of app.html built from the routes in app.js (and maybe routes in someparent.js injecting the child router in the parent or what?).

So essentially what I need is to achieve almost the same thing as basic routing - but as I mentioned I need to have multiple of these routes / pages as partials of a parent view/controller. I couldn't find any info on this from googling extensively for weeks, so hopefully someone in here will be able to understand what I ask, and have an idea of how to go about this in Aurelia, the right way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class to contain your shared state and take a dependency on that class in your view-models. You can use the `NewInstance.of` resolver to control when shared state is created vs reused.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=4cbf5e9fa71ad4f4041556e4595d3e36**

[image]

**shared-state.js**

```js
export class SharedState {
  fromdate = '';
  todate = '';
  language = 'English';
}
```

**shared-parent.js**

```js
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SharedState} from './shared-state';

@inject(NewInstance.of(SharedState)) // <-- this says create a new instance of the SharedState whenever a SharedParent instance is created
export class SharedParent {
  constructor(state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  configureRouter(config, router){
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
        { route: ['', 'child-a'], moduleId: './child-a', nav: true, title: 'Child A' },
        { route: 'child-b', moduleId: './child-b', nav: true, title: 'Child B' },
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

*note: if you use `@inject(SharedState)` instead of `@inject(NewInstance.of(SharedState))`, a single instance of `SharedState` will be shared with all components. This may be what you are looking for, I wasn't sure. The purpose of `@inject(NewInstance.of(SharedState))` is to make sure the parent and it's children have their own `SharedState` instance.*

**child-a.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SharedState} from './shared-state';

@inject(SharedState)
export class ChildA {
  constructor(state) {
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

**child-b.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {SharedState} from './shared-state';

@inject(SharedState)
export class ChildB {
  constructor(state) {
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's the perfect answer. Can't thank you enough for even taking the time to write a code example that works. Amazing! ("You may award your bounty in 20 hours".. bah ;-))

Comment: I do have one more question jeremy. Everytime the "language" (+ more properties in the real code) is changed I used to have a SomethingChanged(newVal, oldVal){} which modified some of the other viewmodel properties. While the SharedState way is nice, I think it would be easier to do something like $parent.someprop? But that doesn't work since the child is within the router-view and not a compose-view, right? I like the SharedState way but say language changes from the parent, and the child needs to mutate some other value of the SharedState object when that happens. How would you handle that?

Comment: I guess sticking with the SharedState approach would be best, but I'm unsure which observation method would be the best. Here https://github.com/axwalker/aurelia-observer-patterns/wiki/Observer-patterns-in-Aurelia there are mentioned both BindingEngine, aurelia-event-aggregator, Signals and even a plugin called aurelia-flux. I'm not sure which of these would be the optimal solutions for observing and reacting to changes in the shared state object.

Comment: I think I figured it out, somewhat. Just injecting SharedParent into ChildA etc., making a reference in the constructor to this.parent = parent is working pretty well. Instead of storing 10+ properties in the SharedState object I'm just setting them directly from the Child like "parent.prop1" etc. Then whenever something changes in the parent I can publish the event with the eventaggregator, and listen for the given channel in the child if something there needs to happen, reload or update. I think the key thing to your answer was the routing - at least that what helped me the most :-)

Comment: I've made a follow-up question to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832255/how-to-dynamically-build-navigation-menu-from-routes-linking-to-parent-child-vie

Answer (score 1):

After better understanding the original question, I would propose the following solution, which takes advantage of the "Additional Data" parameter available in Aurelia's router.  For more information, see http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/4

**app.js**

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  this.router = router;
  config.title = 'My Application Title';
  config.map([
    { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'homefolder/home' },
    { route: 'someparent/child1', name: 'child1', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/someparent', settings: {data: 'child1'} },
    { route: 'someparent/child2', name: 'child2', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/someparent', settings: {data: 'child2'} },
    { route: 'someparent/child3', name: 'child3', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/someparent', settings: {data: 'child3'} }
  ]);
}
```

**someparent.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
@inject(Router)
export class SomeParent {
  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

**someparent.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./child1"></require>
  <require from="./child2"></require>
  <require from="./child3"></require>

  <h1>Some Parent Page Title</h1>

  <div if.bind="router.currentInstruction.config.settings.data == 'child1'">
    <h2>Child Component 1</h2>
    <child-component-one linkeddata.bind="child1"></child-component-one>
  </div>

  <div if.bind="router.currentInstruction.config.settings.data == 'child2'">
    <h2>Child Component 2</h2>
    <child-component-two linkeddata.bind="child2"></child-component-two>
  </div>

  <div if.bind="router.currentInstruction.config.settings.data == 'child3'">
    <h2>Child Component 3</h2>
    <child-component-three linkeddata.bind="child3"></child-component-three>
  </div>

</template>
```

**Additional thoughts:**

I tested the above and it works.  Hopefully by using the route settings data parameters you can "get the message through" to the parent router as to which child you want displayed.  Depending on your specific application, you may prefer to implement this as a sub-router, but simply binding/unbinding the individual child views as I've demonstrated above is a simple solution.  It also shows you how to access the extra parameters you can supply with each route in Aurelia's router.

Comment: Hi LStarky. I appreciate your effort, but I can't help but think there has to be a better way. I've just started a bounty, since I hope for some authorative answer in regards to what would be the best solution. This just seem like a very creative work-around, but if there's no other way, I'd even prefer just to turn the parent (with it's bindable properties and form elements) into a custom element, bind that and just link directly to the child, which now has  the "former parent" (now custom element) embedded. But yeah... that's only if Aurelia doesn't have a clean way to do this :-)

Comment: No worries.  I'd be interested in the best solution also!

Comment: @LStarky, why did you use the "Additional Data" parameter here instead of route name? routeConfig.name can be accessed from the activate function without injecting the whole router. Am I missing something or this is just more general example intended to show how to use more complicated parameters?

Comment: The original question requires sending a message to the child router, and you can't access child route names from a parent.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still relatively new to Aurelia (about 3 months) so there might be a more "expert" answer out there, but what you're trying to do is quite basic.  Remember that Aurelia is based completely on components, to the point that every component is basically an element on a page.  When rendering the "parent" view/controller, your "child" view/controllers are just elements on that parent page.  So you only need to render the parent page and ensure that the child pages are linked correctly.

**Router (in app.js):**

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  this.router = router;
  config.title = 'My Application Title';
  config.map([
    { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'homefolder/home' },
    { route: 'someparent', name: 'someparentnamefornamedroutes-optional', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/someparent' },
  ]);
}
```

**Parent ViewModel (in someparentfolder/someparent.js)**

```
// imports go here, like: import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

// injects go here, like: @inject(MyClass)
export class SomeParent {
  child1 = {
    fname: "Debbie",
    lname: "Smith"
  };
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**Parent View (in someparentfolder/someparent.html)**

```
<template>
  <require from="./child1"></require>
  <require from="./child2"></require>

  <h1>Some Parent Page Title</h1>

  <h2>Child Component 1</h2>
  <child-component-one linkeddata.bind="child1"></child-component-one>

  <h2>Child Component 2</h2>
  <child-component-two></child-component-two>

</template>
```

**Child 1 ViewModel (in someparentfolder/child1.js)**

```
import { inject, bindable, bindingMode } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Core } from 'core';

@inject(Core)
export class ChildComponentOne { // use InitCaps, which will be translated to dash case by Aurelia for the element ref in SomeParent
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) linkeddata;
  constructor(core) {
    this.core = core;
  }
  attached() {
    // example calling core function
    var response = this.core.myCustomFunction();
  }
}
```

**Child 1 View (in someparentfolder/child1.html)**

```
<template>
  <h3>Hello, ${linkeddata.fname}</h3>
  <p>Here's something from core: ${core.value1}</p>
</template>
```

*(Use same concepts for Child 2 ViewModel and View)*

**Navigation Directly to Child Components:**

The above scenario has each of the child components "embedded" in the SomeParent page.  However, if you want to simply open each Child Component as its own navigation router view (to open directly in your main `<router-view></router-view>` content window), just use a router definition like this:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  this.router = router;
  config.title = 'My Application Title';
  config.map([
    { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'homefolder/home' },
    { route: 'someparent', name: 'someparent', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/someparent' },
    { route: 'someparent/child1', name: 'child1', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/child1' },
    { route: 'someparent/child2', name: 'child2', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/child2' },
    { route: 'someparent/child3', name: 'child3', moduleId: 'someparentfolder/child3' }
  ]);
}
```

**One More Scenario:**

Perhaps what you're looking for is a Singular class that contains a common place to store state and common functions that all of your components will access.  I implemented this by creating a model called `core.js`.  I've added those details above, and you would also create the following file in your project root (`/src`) folder.

**Core Class (in /src/core.js):**

```
// Some example imports to support the common class
import { inject, noView } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient, json } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { I18N } from 'aurelia-i18n';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@noView // this decorator is needed since there is no core.html
@inject(EventAggregator, I18N, HttpClient)
export class Core {
  value1 = "Test data 1";
  value2 = "Test data 2";
  constructor(eventAggregator, i18n, httpClient) {
    // store local handles
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  myCustomFunction() {
    // some code here, available to any component that has core.js injected
  }
}
```

**Notes on Binding:**

I gave you an example of how to set up two-way binding to the child component with a JavaScript object.  Aurelia is very flexible and you could do this a lot of different ways but this seems to be fairly standard.  If you don't need the child to manipulate the data contained in `child1`, you could delete the parenthetical notes on the `@bindable` decorator so it would simply be `@bindable linkeddata;`

You can add multiple parameters to link more than one piece of data, or group them into an object or array.

Since I'm still a relatively new user, I remember going through all of this.  Please let me know if you have any follow-up comments or questions.

And by all means, if there are any **true experts** watching this, please teach me as well!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to be able to click a link to each of: child 1, child 2, child 3 etc (or it needs to work that way at least) from the main navigation. The code snippets you've been so kind to provide just "embeds" all of them directly in the parent view as far as I can tell

Comment: When you say "click a link", are you wanting it to scroll to that portion of the SomeParent page?  Or are you wanting it to navigate to each Child as its own page?  If each Child will appear as its own page, you can still use the above code and just change the router.  I'll edit my response to add that information, but if I'm still not understanding, please be more specific.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is a Singular class that contains a common place to store state and common functions that all of your components will access. I implemented this by creating a class (without a view) called `core.js`. I'll write out the details in a moment.

Comment: It is almost correct that I want to "Navigate Directly to Child routes" from a main app router. But not "directly", but rather "to the child, wrapped inside the parent", so I guess you need to somehow route to the parent first, and then to the child from there. But since there isn't a navigation or menu with routes in the parent, I'm kinda lost as to how to do this. I appreciate your example a lot, but it isn't exactly what I'm after. I'll try to put together a plunkr when I get home. Might make it easier to understand

Comment: What's so important about the parent?  If it doesn't have a view... it seems useless.  Unless, of course, you're trying to use the parent to provide the child with some information, in which case the `core.js` above could do that for you.

Comment: The important thing about the parent is of course that it has some markup with customelements and html (a template), bindable properties and stuff which all the children will be reusing. So I appreciate all your efforts, but it's not really solving my problem. The parent is important - it's kinda like a masterpage for the child pages