# Nested routing in aurelia js

Tags: aurelia

Is there any way to have nested routing/child router in Aurelia JS 
as we have in ui-router for angular js?
so that we can achieve following

- Update the partial view (only update a selected portion on the given event).
- having parent child relationship in the components

TIA

Comment: See here to get your answers: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

**Multiple View Ports**

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/9

You can define two or more different views to be affected by a route, by creating more than one `<router-view>` in your template like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view name="left"></router-view>
  </div>
  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view name="right"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

And then defining both destinations in your individual routes:

```
{ route: 'users', name: 'users', viewPorts: { left: { moduleId: 'user/list' }, right: { moduleId: 'user/detail' } } }
```

**Accessing your Router from Parent to Affect Child**

See this post and the first answer for an in-depth explanation for how to access the Router to create parent/child component routing.

[Linking directly to both parent+child views/controllers from the main navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976125/linking-directly-to-child-views-controllers-from-the-parent-router-navigation/40995959#40995959)

In summary, you probably need to access your main router by injecting it into any parent components that need child routing, like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
@inject(Router)
export class SomeParent {
  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

**More Examples**

You should check out the skeleton-navigation examples at https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation. There are good examples, including how to do child routing.

Comment: FWIW nested child routers and such do not rely on view ports so I think for completeness it would be nice to add at the top that you can use a child router and it will work as intended without any additional work.